# Javascript devuelve indefinido en las etiquetas html pero muestra el resultado en la consola del desarrollador

Tags: javascript, datatables, javascript-objeto

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy trabajando con la libreria javascript DataTable, el detalle se encuentra al renderizar una de las columnas ya que me muestra el output como indefinido pero en la consola se desarollador se muestra correctamente, que estoy haciendo mal?, este es un fragmento del codigo donde tengo el problema:

```
// array de los datos
datos = "members": [
{"id": 1,
"company_id": 1,
"name": "Abdiel Hernandez",
"email": "hh.abdiel@gmail.com",
"email_verified_at": "2022-09-10T05:37:30.000000Z",
"two_factor_confirmed_at": null,
"current_team_id": null,
"profile_photo_path": "profile-photos/lwUGpvXbewwVHslBSU84gRePV5taE6tI5QFSKB8O.jpg",
"created_at": "2022-09-10T05:36:58.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2022-09-10T16:10:49.000000Z",
"profile_photo_url": "http://workstinger-starter-kit.test/storage/profile-photos/lwUGpvXbewwVHslBSU84gRePV5taE6tI5QFSKB8O.jpg",
"pivot": {
"requisition_id": 1,
"user_id": 1 }}],
```

fragmento de codigo javascript:

```
render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
        var $status = full['members'];

        return '<div class="avatar-group">' +
               $status.forEach(element => console.log(
               '<div data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-popup="tooltip-custom" data-bs-placement="top" class="avatar pull-up my-0" title="' + element.name +'" >' +
                    '<img src="' + element.profile_photo_url +'" alt="Avatar" height="26" width="26"/>' +
               '</div>'
              )) + '<small class="text-truncate text-muted align-self-center cursor-pointer ms-50 mb-0">+42</small>' +
              '</div>'
          }
```

espero puedan ayudar a e contrar el error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tanto [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) como [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Console/log) devuelven `undefined`, por lo cual no puedes usarlos para concatenar valores como lo tratas de hacer.

Lo que intentas, se puede lograr usando `forEach` de la siguiente forma:

```js
render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
  var $status = full['members'];
  var element = '<div class="avatar-group">';
  $status.forEach(e => {
    element += '<div data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-popup="tooltip-custom" data-bs-placement="top" class="avatar pull-up my-0" title="' +
      e.name + '" ><img src="' +
      e.profile_photo_url +'" alt="Avatar" height="26" width="26"/></div>';
  });
  element += '<small class="text-truncate text-muted align-self-center cursor-pointer ms-50 mb-0">+42</small>' + '</div>'
  return element;
}
```

En el código estoy declarando una variable llamada `element` y le asigno un valor inicial. Luego, recorro la lista de elementos de `$status` y voy concatenando los elementos a la variable `elemento`. Finalmente cierro el valor de `elemento` fuera del bucle y devuelvo el `elemento` procesado.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Tienes toda la razon, el problema a quedado solucionado, eres un master!